# Appcelerator: Touchmove to drag view gives very "jumpy" result

Tags: appcelerator, drag, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to drag a view in android environment using Appcelerator and it turns out to have a very jumpy animation. The codes are as below:

```
newmainwindow.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    xPos = e.x;
    yPos = e.y;
});

newmainwindow.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){

    var conPoint = newmainwindow.convertPointToView({x:e.x, y:e.y}, mainview);

    console.log("global y: " + conPoint.y);

    var moveY = conPoint.y - yPos;
    moveY /= 2;

    console.log("global diff y: " + moveY);

    newmainwindow.top = Math.abs(moveY);
});

newmainwindow.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    console.log("end");
});
```

I have searched for a lot of solutions but unfortunately none of them works. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The challenge with draggable views in Titanium is that the bridge between JS and native becomes a bottleneck because all the feedback back and forth.

Hyperloop (beta) allows you to directly use platform APIs. The example app also has samples for dragging views:

https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pec1985/TiDraggable

I used this and it's an absolutely great solution. Works out of the box.